# what the reason to function oninput in js is not work?

Tags: javascript, html

there are practical video uploaded by someone and i do step by step what do you write in video ( i mean codes ) but nothing is !

the used language ( html and js )

```js
var $count = document.getElementById("count"),
    $textarea = document.getElementById("text"),
    $maxlength = $textarea.getAttribute("maxlength");

$maxlength.oninput = function () {
    $count.innerHTML = $maxlength - this.value.length;
};
```

```html
  <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.css">
    <title>cal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="100"></textarea>
        <span id="count">100</span>
    </form>
<script src="cal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: shoudnt it be $textarea.oninput instead of  $maxlength.oninput?

Comment: The reason is that [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute#syntax) are not [`EventTarget`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). Link to the video, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not `$maxlength`, use `$textarea` to listen `oninput` event.

```js
var $count = document.getElementById("count"),
    $textarea = document.getElementById("text"),
    $maxlength = $textarea.getAttribute("maxlength");

$textarea.oninput = function () {
    $count.innerHTML = $maxlength - this.value.length;
};
```

```html
  <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.css">
    <title>cal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="100"></textarea>
        <span id="count">100</span>
    </form>
<script src="cal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```